# ¿Cómo eliminar una base de datos vuforia en Unity?

Tags: unity3d, vuforia

Tengo un proyecto en Unity en el cual tengo dos bases de datos de vuforia las cuáles contienen los targets, pero una base ya no la voy a ocupar y quisiera eliminarla del proyecto, pero no encuentro una opción para eliminarla.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que buscar dentro de Assets -> Editor -> Qcar -> Seleccionas tu base de datos y Suprimir.

Comment: La carpeta Qcar no existe dentro de Editor.